# C++ frequently changing list of structs - keep only pointers or entire structs?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

I have a class for each entity in game, which has a child class used for managing some attributes of this entity.
The attribute managing class holds a std::list of structs, each struct has data about a single attribute and a few simple functions to manipulate that data.
Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate it:

```
struct stAttribute
{
    /* data & functions */
}

class AttributeManager
{
    std::list<struct stAttribute> attributeList;
    /* ... */
};

class Entity
{
    AttributeManager attribMgr;
    /* .... */
};

int main(void)
{
    Entity ent;

    struct stAttribute newAttrib;
    /* ... */
    ent.attribMgr.attributeList.push_back(x);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Entities are frequently created & deleted in the game at runtime, the same goes for the attributes.

I start having doubts whether creating them 'statically' and keeping entire structs in the list is a good choice. My main concern is the performance.
Would it be better to allocate memory dynamically and store only pointers to the structs? Freeing the memory isn't any problem because the deletion of attributes is handled by the AttributeManager class.

Comment: Take a look at this from cppcon 2018; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yy8jQgmhbAU  It's a detailed look at the impact of program structure, OOP v Data Oriented Design. Insightful talk.

Comment: You don't want `std::list`. The only "good" reason I can think of to use `std::list` is if you want stable pointers to list elements, and that's not a good reason, that's a bad reason. Use vector.

Comment: Write both, then profile. That said,  Paul's right in his answer. There's rarely a need for pointers in a `std::list` outside polymorphism because list has very forgiving iterator invalidation. `list` also has poor cache and and branch prediction friendliness, so you might want to throw a `std::vector` into the mix to see if its O(1) access and cache-friendliness while iterating advantages outweigh the O(N) disadvantage when removing an element.

Answer (score 1):

My $0.02: having your list 'own' your `stAttribute` objects seems entirely appropriate to me - that's the way things are usually done in general and the fact that they come and go frequently wouldn't change my view on that.

However, do investigate the `emplace_xxx` functions offered by `std::list` (which eliminate the copy operation implied by, e.g., `push_back`) and be sure that a `std::list` is the optimal container for your use-case before you commit to it.

Comment: `list`'s specialty is comes and goes quickly whether owns the contents or not. You're probably going to be slower with the pointer due to the addition of an extra level of pointer chasing and the extra (assuming here) dynamic memory management.